# How to add value from specific datatable column into datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have datatable but this datatable clone value from another datatable(query from database).

```
 public void showData()
 {
     string conStr = @"Data Source= ...";
     onnection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
     connection.Open();
     command = new SqlCommand();
     sql = "something"; 
     command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
     adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
     dtt = new DataTable();
     adapter.Fill(dtt);
     //--Somthing Generate--//
     DataTable dt = new Datatable();
     dt = dtt.Clone();
     //--Somthing Generate--//
}
```

And i try add valec from datatable(dt) specific columns.

```
dt = dtt.Clone();
//--Somthing Generate--//
dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView3.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "ID";
dataGridView3.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Name";
```

from my code ,I can not it.

Comment: use Copy() method instead of clone.

Comment: I can not use Copy() because I need convert datatype of data. @Atk

Comment: Both the Copy and the Clone methods create a new DataTable with the same structure as the original DataTable.
Clone method can not create datarow but Copy method create both structure and datarow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Use Copy() method instead of Clone().**

```
dt = dtt.Copy();
```

2. **Set the AutoGenerateColumns property of gridview to false.**

When the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true, each column automatically sets its DataPropertyName property to the name of a property or database column in the data source specified by the DataSource property. This binding can also be performed manually, which is useful when you want to display only a subset of the properties or database columns available in the data source. In such cases, set the AutoGenerateColumns property to false, and then manually add each DataGridViewColumn, setting the value of each DataPropertyName property to the properties or database columns in the data source that you want to display.